# geom_bar define border color with different fill colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw a bar plot with `geom_bar` where I want unique fill colors surrounded by a black border. However the instruction `color="black"` is  not interpreted as "black" as I want it to be and I get red borders.

```
library(ggplot2)
test=as.data.frame(cbind(a=c(1,1,2,3), b=1:4, c=as.character(1:4)))
ggplot(test) + geom_bar(aes(x=a, y=b, fill=c, colour="black"), stat="identity")
```

How do I correctly use `geom_bar` so that it gives me the correct black border?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You have to put `colour` outside `aes`:

```
ggplot(test) + geom_bar(aes(x=a, y=b, fill=c), colour="black", stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, this is because everything inside `aes` is interpreted as a column in the data. By defining the color aesthetic as `"black"`, it's as if you had a column that read "black" in every row, and then you told ggplot to make group colors conditional on the values in that column. That's why it automatically makes a legend for it, for one. By putting it outside the `aes`, you're telling ggplot to treat it as a single fixed color indicator - as a name, hexadecimal, or whatever.