# Wrong border colors on geom_bar plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a bar chart of counts of fish in various length categories by sampling week.
Here is a bit of the database called Chin:

```
Trib    Week   Size2  
MM      21     90
SM      21     80
SM      22     100
NM      22     8p
```

I have converted `Size2` to a factor called `Fork`, and week to a factor called `period`.

Here is my code:

```
period<-as.factor(Chin$week)
Chin1<-cbind(Chin, period)
Fork<-as.factor(Chin$Size2)

g <- ggplot(Chin1, aes(period))
g + geom_bar(aes(fill=Fork))+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, 
 vjust=0.6)) +  theme_bw() +scale_fill_manual(values=c("white","gray90", 
"gray82", "gray61", "gray48", "black"))
```

This works great except there is no border around the bars or the elements of the legend:

[image: Chart with no borders]

But when I add `colour="black"` in this line to get black borders:

```
g + geom_bar(aes(fill=Fork, colour="black"))+ theme(axis.text.x 
element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6))....
```

I instead get red borders with a new legend with an item called `"black"`  I get this no matter what color I choose.  The name of the legend item changes (i.e. blue, green) but the border color stays red and the legend item fill is still black.  See below.  I know this must be a simple silly mistake, but I cannot figure it out.  Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

[image: Chart with red borders]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [geom\_bar define border color with different fill colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709972/geom-bar-define-border-color-with-different-fill-colors)

Answer (score 4):

Move the `colour="black"` outside the aes() statement.  aes() uses variables from your data to create aesthetics, so you're saying to base color off of the column "black", which doesn't exist.

Also found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709972/geom-bar-define-border-color-with-different-fill-colors)